# Select from two tables joid vs Joining two Selects

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, join, db2

**I always see people use these two ways for joining two or more tables.**

```
select *
from BOOKS as B
where B.name = 'GOOD BOOK'
inner join select *
from AUTHOR as A
where A.AUTHOR_NAME = 'GOOD AUTHOR' on B.BOOK_ID = A.BOOK_ID

select *
from BOOKS as B
inner join AUTHOR as A on B.BOOK_ID = A.BOOK_ID
where B.name = 'GOOD BOOK'
    and A.AUTHOR_NAME = 'GOOD AUTHOR'
```

**I wonder which is faster (better performance) to use and why?**

Comment: Neither is valid syntax for Oracle (second is closer, but lose the `as` in the table aliases). No idea if the first is OK for MySQL or DB2. The answer may be different for the the three databases you tagged this for anyway. Have you done any performance testing with real data in the database you're actually using, or looked at execution plans etc.?

Comment: first is not valid for db2, i dont think into mysql

Comment: The question is about the benchmark difference, not the validity of the code. From the example is clear that the author asks how to better construct the query performance-wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took your two examples and re-wrote them (in Oracle) using EMP and DEPT. I believe these queries represent what you are trying to do; if not, feel free to correct me. I also added @mathguy's example (re-written)

```
select *
from EMP E
inner join ( select *
             from DEPT D
             where d.loc = 'DALLAS' ) d1
on d1.deptno = e.deptno
where e.job = 'CLERK'


select *
from DEPT D
inner join EMP E
on D.deptno = E.deptno
where d.loc = 'DALLAS'
and e.job = 'CLERK'

select * 
from  ( select * from dept where loc = 'DALLAS' ) D
inner join
      ( select * from emp where job = 'CLERK' ) E
on e.deptno = d.deptno
```

I generated the execution plan for all the queries and it turns out they are all the same. Oracle will perform Cost Based Transformations - basically re-writing your query in order to generate the best execution plan. The execution plan is as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |       |       |     4 (100)|          |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN         |      |     1 |    59 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| DEPT |     1 |    20 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |     4 |   156 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("E"."DEPTNO"="D"."DEPTNO")
   2 - filter("D"."LOC"='DALLAS')
   3 - filter("E"."JOB"='CLERK')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your intent is clear, even though the syntax is wrong. Using Oracle syntax (which I believe is all SQL Standard for the two queries below), you want to know if it is more efficient to apply WHERE conditions to each table separately and only then to do the join, or if it is cheaper to do the join and then to apply the WHERE conditions to the joined rows.

The answer is, in almost all cases, it should be cheaper to apply the WHERE conditions first - especially if you have indexes and such which can be used for efficient access to the base table rows. This is because almost always the I/O to access rows on hard disk is either the most time consuming or one of the most time consuming operations. Using an index, the query engine may be able to read only a small number of rows from one table or the other (or both) before any operations happen in the CPU.

With that said, speaking only for Oracle (the only one I know), what you need are two things: (1) some familiarity with Google, and (2) the phrase to search, which is "predicate pushing". In a case as simple as yours, the Oracle optimizer will "push" the predicates (the WHERE conditions) to each base table, even if you use the second syntax. You can see that easily if you run an Explain Plan for your second query.

For completeness, here is the correct syntax for the two queries. (In general you shouldn't use * in a SELECT clause - you should name the columns individually - but you didn't describe any actual tables, so I have no choice.)

```
select *
from (select * from books   where name = 'Good Book'  ) b
        inner join
     (select * from authors where name = 'Good Author') a
        on b.book_id = a.book_id
```

(Incidentally, that is an odd arrangement - I would rather expect the `authors` table to have primary key `author_id` and `books` to have a foreign key `author_id` referencing `authors`, and the join would be on these columns... but again, I understand this is not an actual setting.)

**versus**

```
select * from books b inner join authors a on b.book_id = a.book_id
where a.name = 'Good Author' and b.name = 'Good Book'
```